# Apply an iOS 7 style blur to a table view section header

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, graphics

I want to apply a blur effect, similar to what you see in the control center drag up, in the table section header of a table view. I have looked at some GitHub repos, like iOS-blur and LiveFrost, but they don't seem to work. They don't actually blur the table cells that are scrolling past the section header, but they blur the content of the section view, which is exactly what I want to avoid.

Any suggestions?

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    UITableViewCell *headerView = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SetSelectionHeaderCell"];

    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    //LFGlassView *glassView = [[LFGlassView alloc] initWithFrame:headerView.frame];
    JCRBlurView *glassView = [JCRBlurView new];
    [glassView setFrame:headerView.frame];
    [glassView setBlurTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [headerView addSubview:glassView];

    [headerView sendSubviewToBack:glassView];


    return headerView;
}
```

Comment: How are you adding the blur view to the section header? Can we see some code? I assume you are using `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`?

Comment: added -- it's simple stuff because I haven't implemented the logic to change the view -- i want to get the blur effect working first, or at least told i can't do that. I've tried iOS-Blur and FrostLive and other github plugins, but they don't seem to blur the right thing. I think part of the problem is I don't know how to insert a view and float it at the top of a table view  (in front of the cells, but behind the section header view) If i could do that, at least I'd partially be there.

Comment: When you say you tried iOS-Blur, do you mean that you returned an instance of the iOS-Blur view as the headerView in `tableView:vieForHeaderInSection:` or that you added the blur view as a subview of the header view? Could you try setting the headerView background color to clear and adding and iOS-Blur (aka UIToolbar) as a subview of the headerView?

Comment: I added it at as a subview of the headerview and all it did was blur out the header text

Comment: LFGlassView *glassView = [[LFGlassView alloc] initWithFrame:headerView.frame];
    [headerView addSubview:glassView];

    return headerView;

Comment: Okay, well if the headerView is not transparent then you won't see anything behind it, so set `headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]`. Additionally you will have to send the glassView to the back with `sendSubviewToBack:` so it is not on top of the text. Let me know if that works.

Comment: That unblurred the text, but just made the view white https://www.dropbox.com/s/ztzeb8dz8xqhoyv/Screenshot%202014-04-30%2022.47.13.png

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure why the text color changed, it may be default behavior of the UITableViewCell when the background color is changed. Set the cell's label text color to black then. If it is not a performance issue I would suggest just instantiating a plain old UIView and returning that as the headerView.

Comment: I updated my code to reflect our discussion. it now looks like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/bdqw3n4lopclqcl/Screenshot%202014-04-30%2023.01.17.png if you look closely..you can see the text in the right back of the view..but it doesnt look blurred. Frustrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are adding the `blurView` as a subview of the headerView, but the backgroundColor of the headerView is by default white, and therefore opaque. In order to see the views behind the headerView you need to make the headerView transparent. You can do this by setting

```
headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]
```

The `iOS-Blur` view works by blurring views behind it. So the reason you are seeing the title label of the headerView blurred out is because the `blurView` was added as a subview to the `headerView` after the label was added. This puts the `blurView` in front of the label, as the topmost subview. You need to send the blur view all the way to the back after you have added it as a subview.

```
[headerView sendSubviewToBack:blurView];
```

If you make the `headerView` transparent and you add the `blurView` at the back, it should work as you want it to.

The result should look like this:

[image: this]

I should also note, that if you are adding a subview to the `headerView` every time you  dequeue it as a tableView cell, the subviews will accumulate.

Comment: let me actually try iOS-Blur instead of LF-Blur ( was trying to preserve iOS compatibility). Not sure if the blue effect will work properly on the simulator though -- it looks like on the sim it is just directly showing through the tint. the table behind it.. It just looks translucent with an alpha, not blurred

Comment: Have you tested this solution to work on table views?

Comment: I just tested it by just using a UIToolbar instead of iOS-Blur (which is what an iOS-Blur view is), and it appears to be just as transparent and blurry as the navigation controller. https://www.dropbox.com/s/em8ov9bt65jje8u/IMG_9475.png Note the blurry green on the left side in front of the picture.

Comment: I have a feeling it is the simulator. I'll give it a try tomorrow on a real device (I left my charger at work) Thanks.

Comment: Hey I think your solution worked, sorry for the late response, but thank you!